# Mapstruct: mapping by condition

Tags: java, mapstruct

I should return several fields from `ShipmentResponseDto.cargo.packaging.lastMeasurements` as `null` if `shipping.status==Status.Opened`. Like this:

```
if(shipment.status=Status.Opened){
   ShipmentResponseDto.cargo.packaging.lastMeasurements.firstField = null;
   ShipmentResponseDto.cargo.packaging.lastMeasurements.secondField = null;
}
```

I want to do it in mapstruct. The whole problem is that the answer is assembled from two mappers and I did not succeed in implementing this.

```
@Mapper(uses = {
    CargoPackagingMapper.class
})
public interface ShipmentMapper extends BasicMapper<ShipmentResponseDto, Shipment> {

}


@Mapper(uses = {PackagingTypeMapper.class})
public abstract class CargoPackagingMapper implements BasicMapper<CargoPackagingResponseDto, Packaging> {

    @Override
    @Mappings(...)
    public abstract CargoPackagingResponseDto toDto(Packaging source);
}

public class Shipment {

    ...
    ...
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    private Set<ShipmentCargo> cargo = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}

public class ShipmentCargo {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Packaging packaging;
    ...

}
public class Packaging {
    ...
    
    private PackagingLastMeasurements lastMeasurements;
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is defining the [`@AfterMapping`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) method in the `ShipmentMapper` that sets those fields to `null`, as follows:

```java
@AfterMapping
default void setFieldsToNullIfStatusIsOpen(Shipment shipment, @MappingTarget ShipmentResponseDto response) {
  if(shipment.getStatus()==Status.Opened){
    PackagingLastMeasurements plm = response.getCargo().getPackaging().getLastMeasurements();
    plm.setFirstField(null);
    plm.setSecondField(null);
  }
}
```